# How do I check the User's IP in a Request subscriber/listener in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Some users of my application will have an `allowedIPs` array attached. There was a [guide](http://symfony2-document.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/security/voters.html) for an authentication `Voter` for blacklisting IPs which I could adapt to whitelist a user's IP based on who is authenticating.

The problem I see here is a scenario where a user authenticates while in one allowed network, *then switches to another network where the user is not allowed to connect from.*

I think the solution would be to have a subscriber to the `kernel.request` event, where I deauthorize the user if the IP is not allowed.

Is this sort of IP checking on each request a stupid approach? If it's not, how do I get the authenticated user in the event subscriber? The `GetResponseEvent` ([api docs](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/GetResponseEvent.html)) doesn't seem to give any method from which to get the authenticated user if one exists.

**EDIT:** As Cerad suggested, I did this with a voter.

Voter class

```
<?php

namespace My\UserBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\AuthenticatedVoter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use My\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class ValidClientIpVoter extends AuthenticatedVoter
{
    private $container;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
    {
        $request = $this->container->get('request');
        $user = $token->getUser();

        // vote on instances of our User class
        if($user instanceof User) {
            $allowed_ips = $user->getAllowedIps();

            // only vote if there actually are limitations
            if(is_array($allowed_ips) && count($allowed_ips)) {
                $this->logger->debug(sprintf('ValidClientIpVoter: Validating allowed IPs for user #%d', $user->getId()));

                // deny access if current request's IP is not allowed for the user
                if(!in_array($request->getClientIp(), $allowed_ips)) {
                    $this->logger->notice(sprintf('ValidClientIpVoter: Invalid client IP for user #%d', $user->getId()));

                    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
                }
            }
        }

        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

}
```

changes to `security.yml` to make voting unanimous

```
security:
    access_decision_manager: 
        strategy: unanimous
```

and finally the service definition

```
services:
   valid_client_ip_voter:
        class:      My\UserBundle\Security\ValidClientIpVoter
        arguments:  [@service_container, @monolog.logger]
        public:     false
        tags:
            -       { name: security.voter }
```

Comment: If you really wanted to do this then inject the security.token_storage service into your listener: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object.  I would actually listen to kernel.controller just to make sure the user is available.  On the other hand, voters get called on each access so I am unclear why your existing approach would not still work.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think that through. I somehow imagined the voter only into the login process where the authed session is set. If you feel like turning your comment to an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current user, inject the security.token_storage service into your listener: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object

I would actually listen to kernel.controller just to make sure the user is available.

On the other hand, voters get called on each access to a resource so I am unclear why your existing approach would not work even if the ip changes.